# Is it BAD to use the $_SESSION superglobal to get the current online users, and set it back to the current session data later?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a database to store my session data. I've created some functions to query through the current active sessions and return some values to be used on the current page. Getting the number of open sessions seems easy enough with a single query like 
    "SELECT SessionData FROM UserSessions"
and return the number of rows returned by the query.

I then wanted to determine which site users are currently "online". The session stores the UserID of the user who is viewing the website. I searched and searched and seemed to only find the session_decode function for decoding what seems to be serialized data (but unserialize doesn't work). The only problem here is, session_decode automatically populates the $_SESSION superglobal. So my question is, is it "BAD" to temporarily store the $_SESSION data, use session_decode on each user that is currently online, then reset the $_SESSION variable to the temporarily stored data?

```
function getLoggedInUsers() {
            //NEED SOME ERROR HANDLING AROUND DB STUFF
    $oConn = DB::connect(RF_DSN);

    $oPrep = $oConn->prepare("SELECT SessionData FROM UserSessions WHERE SessionData LIKE ?");

    $oRes = $oConn->execute($oPrep, array("%UserID%"));

    $aCurSession = $_SESSION; //STORE SESSION DATA TO RESET LATER

    $aLoggedInUsers = array();
    while ($oRow = $oRes->fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
        if ($oRow == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        $_SESSION = array();

        session_decode($oRow["SessionData"]);

        $aLoggedInUsers[] = new User($_SESSION["UserID"]);

        $_SESSION = array();
    }

    $_SESSION = $aCurSession; //RESET SESSION DATA TO CURRENT ONLINE USER

    return $aLoggedInUsers;
}
```

It seems to me that this would work, but are there any known cases where this could fail and then the current user would end up with some other user's session data, effectively being signed in as a possible admin or something? Would it be better to store another field in my UserSessions database that would house the UserID or something like that?

**EDIT***
I am trying to display the usernames of all the current logged in users (whom have registered on the site, and logged in).

Comment: To clarify, have you written your own session handler for the database that you register with `session_set_save_handler`?  If so you can add a column that stores when a session was last accessed/modified and just use that to determine logged in users with a single query.

Comment: Can't you just run a COUNT(*) query on the SessionData table to find out the number of rows (assuming each row is an active session) and just print the result of that query? Using the _SESSION superglobal like you are seems a little unnecessary for just finding the number of active sessions unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @drew010 Yes, I have. The UserSessions table uses 3 fields. SessionID, SessionData, LastAccessed. The LastAccess is used to remove sessions that have been active for more than a certain amount of time. Are you suggesting using the actual Users table instead of a Sessions table?

Comment: @user1612290 I must have skipped over that part! I am trying to display the usernames of the current sessions that pertain to users who are registered on the site.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler I'd suggest just extended your session table to hold a bit more information.  It sounds like an additional column containing the username would be helpful.  Also adding an index to that column and the LastAccessed column would make those queries more efficient.  Then you could issue a query like `SELECT UserName FROM UserSessions WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - LastAccessed <= *online_time*`  Assuming your LastAccessed column just holds a Unix timestamp something like this might work.

Comment: @drew010 +1 for simplicity, though just making that lastaccessed field a mysql `timestamp` would give you the auto-update for free, without having to mess with unix timestamp conversions.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks for the info! That's kinda what I was thinking after writing that function. One more question: Should I just use the $_SESSION superglobal in the write_session() function, since it is passed the serialized data which can't be unserialized?

Answer (score 3):

What I would recommend is that you add a column to your session table which stores the user id separately outside of the session data. That way you can use SQL to get the names like this. (Using a hypothetical user table)

```
SELECT UserTable.userName FROM SessionData
INNER JOIN UserTable
ON SessionData.userId = UserTable.id
```

Assuming you're using another query to clean out old sessions after a pre-determined period of time this query will return both the the current session data for each logged in user as well as the user's row from the user table containing their username.

The `$_SESSION` array should only be used for storing information relevant to the user's current session, not other sessions around the site.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I will need to use the $_SESSION variable in my write_session() handler since it is passed the serialized data already. So just set the UserID of the session table to the $_SESSION UserID, correct?

Comment: The `userId` field in the sessions table should correspond to the `id` field (or whatever it's named) in the User table, which assuming your application makes any sense should also be the `$_SESSION['UserId']` value for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into value judgments of good and bad but there's definitely going to be simpler ways to do it.  The simplest would be to just have a DB table that you upsert on every page access with a user ID and a timestamp and do a `COUNT(*)` against the last 15 minutes or so.  With proper indexing, the performance impact would be negligible

Reading some of the comments you posted clarifying what you're doing, you could just as easily do this against your session table.  Since "users online" is not really critical, the possibility of a user being logged in twice and having multiple sessions isn't really all that important.

Comment: Thanks! That is sort of what I am doing now. And about the users being logged in twice, I just added a function to remove old sessions for that UserID into the login script.